# "WiFi sync" over VPN

Tags: sync, vpn

While attached to a VPN, many apps (including Google Photos) will not sync, as they are waiting "for WiFi". Is there a way to make Android treat a VPN (or even better, a VPN running over WiFi) as WiFi for the purposes of syncing?